# Display data elements but do not store them in the database

Tags: javascript, php, database, database-design

I know this is a vague problem... and I personally think a stupid one as well. Not really looking for an answer just hopefully some suggestions and thoughts.

I have in internal Client who is not technical at all but insists on dictating HOW stuff is to be done and not just WHAT. I am working on a PHP tool which uses Google Charts. Let's say I have a simple column chart "amount of sales per Manager". This Client wants the NAMES of the managers to be visible on the chart, so for example:
John Smith : $200,000
Jane Smith : $150,000
Jim Smith : $250,000
But they do not want the names to be stored in the database. Rather, they want "unique identifiers" in the database (manger0001, manager 0002 etc) .. and then they want "SOMEHOW" for the tool to replace those identifiers with managers' names...

Let me add that it's not just manager's names. its client's, locations, units... basically THOUSANDS of values which I am not supposed to store in the database but "SOMEHOW" display on the page.

What do you guys think?

Comment: Do you really want manger0001 format ? or are you okay with any unreadable format ?

Comment: @Sree , not only is my internal Client OK with an "unreadable" format ..thay actually insisted that the value in the database is as UNreadable as possible

Answer (score 1):

You could create a JSON file (or any other configuration file) which links the key (manager001) to the name (John Smith). Upon loading the keys from the database, load the JSON file and do the appropriate replacements.

Comment: yeah, I considered something like that. The thing is that the tool I am building also lets the user build queries in a "user friendly" way... so now I would need to build a mechanisim that first translates "john smith" into "Manager001" so that the db can be queried  .. and than all the results would need to be translated back into the "john smith" format ... just shoot me now.

Comment: Haha well, it's not too complicated. Just start the application with a bootstrap function that converts all of the data into an easy-to-use array, and from there you can use PHP's array functions :)

Answer (score 1):

You can encrypt the data when storing into database and decrypt that while displaying

There are different methods to encrypt in php

> base64 ,md5,Hash,mcrypt etc

you can use any of the reversible encryption method(As you want to display the data in readable format)

Comment: yeah, this would work in a NORMAL situation ;) I discussed encryption but .... ;/ this would just open up a whole big endless conversation about can the encryptions be broken/hacked... do they comply with all of our legel agreements and contracts and security policies .... I'm not saying this isn't a good idea :) i'm just saying that a NON - technical person is telling me HOW to do my job ;)

Comment: @MikePala : Some of the encryption mechanism are not get hacked .Because you only knows(or your team) which word you used to encrypt.You can learn more about strong encryption mechanisms